# Override right border for second and third ToggleButton in ToggleButtonGroup

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js, material-ui

I have been at this for a good few hours and I cannot seem to make it work.

I am using Mui v5. Currently I have am trying to make the ToggleButtons look like normal MUI buttons.

I was able to achieve this:

[image]

from this:

[image]

with the following custom theme:

```js
import { createTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";

let theme = createTheme();

export const CustomTheme = createTheme(theme, {
  components: {
    MuiButton: {
      defaultProps: {
        disableRipple: true,
      },
    },
    MuiToggleButton: {
      defaultProps: {
        disableRipple: true,
      },
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          transition: "",
          width: "6.30rem",
          height: "2.3rem",
          textTransform: "capitalize",
          color: theme.palette.primary.main,

          "&:hover": { backgroundColor: "transparent" },
          "&.MuiButtonBase-root": { borderRadius: "1rem" },
          "&.MuiToggleButtonGroup-grouped": {
            borderRadius: "5px !important",
            border: "1px solid !important",
            borderColor: theme.palette.primary.light + " !important",
          },
          "&.Mui-selected, &.Mui-selected:hover": {
            color: "white",
            backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.main,
            borderColor: theme.palette.primary.main,
            borderColor: theme.palette.primary.main + " !important",
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

I found this somewhere on StackOverflow and I cannot remember where. I just copy pasted and it worked.

I am unable to determine how I can target this specific class:

[image]

**Questions:**

1. Is there a better way to make the border change instead of just doing "!important" on the `MuiToggleButtonGroup-grouped` class?
2. How can I target the above class `MuiToggleButtonGroup-root .MuiToggleButtonGroup-grouped:not(:last-of-type)` and make my own changes to it? Like, if I wanted to have a different style on the "nth" child of the button group.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it doing something like this:

```
MuiToggleButtonGroup: {
...theme.components?.MuiToggleButtonGroup,
styleOverrides: {
  grouped: {
    '&:not(:last-of-type)': {
      border: `1px solid ${theme.palette.brand.lightGray}`,
      borderRadius: 4,
      '&:hover': {
        boxShadow: 'none',
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        border: `2px solid ${theme.palette.brand.slateBlue}`,
      },
    },
    '&:not(:first-of-type)': {
      margin: 'inherit',
      border: `1px solid ${theme.palette.brand.lightGray}`,
      borderRadius: 4,
      '&:hover': {
        boxShadow: 'none',
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        border: `2px solid ${theme.palette.brand.slateBlue}`,
      },
    },
  },
},
```

},

I hope this solution can solve your problem.